# TFS 2013 - WorkItemChangedEvent not being raised - Configuration?

Tags: c#, plugins, tfs

We have a custom TFS plugin (written in C#) that we use to subscribe to work item changes.

We are in the process of upgrading to TFS 2013, so we are upgrading the plugin.

Unfortunately, the plugin does not respond to WorkItemChangedEvents. The same plugin responded to these without any issues in TFS2012.

Is there a flag somewhere in the TFS configuration to disable these events that we might have set? The plugin will pick up other event types, so I'm not sure if the plugin is the problem.

I've been using a very simple plugin to test which events are raised. The C# code for this is below:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestSubscriber
{
    class TestSubscriber : ISubscriber
    {
        #region ISubscriber Members

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "TestSubscriber"; }
        }

        public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get { return SubscriberPriority.Normal; }
        }

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[3] { typeof(WorkItemsChangedNotification), typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent), typeof(SendEmailNotification) };
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext,
            NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode,
            out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            statusMessage = string.Empty;
            properties = null;

            if (notificationEventArgs is WorkItemsChangedNotification)
            {
                TeamFoundationEventLogger.Log("Received WorkItemsChangedNotification", 0, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            else if (notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
            {
                TeamFoundationEventLogger.Log("Received WorkItemChangedEvent", 0, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }
            else if (notificationEventArgs is SendEmailNotification)
            {
                TeamFoundationEventLogger.Log("Received SendEmailNotification", 0, EventLogEntryType.Information);
            }

            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is a list of the references for the visual studio project:

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Core
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi
- System
- System.Core

If I make a change to a work item that triggers an email (I assign a work item to myself), the subscriber receives a SendEmailNotification, but no WorkItemChangedEvent. If I make a change that won't send an email (state change on another work item), the subscriber does not get notified.

If anyone has any suggestions of what I'm doing incorrectly, do tell. I've been scratching my head over this for some time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. Turns out what I had done was deployed my plugin in the wrong place. I had it under Job Agent/Plugins when it should have been under Web Services/Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
                {
```